# Visual studio emulator for android get stuck in Azure VM

Tags: azure, android-emulator, visual-studio-2015

[image: screenshot]

I'm hosting my development machine on a Azure VM(size of d3), which started by a Windows 8.1 enterprise N image, after the successful install of VS 2015 RC community, I get stuck while I'm try to start the VS emulator for Android, as you can see in the screenshot, it keeps saying "preparing virtual machine...".
Question: how can I launch the emulator?

Comment: The VS Android emulator is an Hyper-V virtual machine.  It's not possible to add the Hyper-V role to a virtualized machine like an Azure VM so you can't run the Android emulator.

Comment: Thanks for point this out, hope this can help other guys who may have the same concern as mine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to check the "Current Limitations" section of the [introductory post on the Visual Studio Emulator for Android](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/11/12/introducing-visual-studio-s-emulator-for-android.aspx). Because the emulator is a Hyper-V VM, Azure uses Hyper-V for VMs, and Hyper-V does not support nested virtualization, you can't run the emulator on Azure yet.